# DefaultTableModel is not displayed in the GUI

Tags: java, swing, oop, jtable

I created a `DefaultTableModel` model which is not getting displayed in my `GUI`. It just shows as a black line. Need to understand why?

Thank you for your help.

The code for the `DefaultTableModel` is:

```
public class MyTableModel {

public static DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

public MyTableModel() {

    model.addColumn("Col1");
    model.addColumn("Col2");
    model.addColumn("Col2");
    model.addColumn("Col2");
    model.addColumn("Col2");
    model.addColumn("Col2");

    model.addRow(new Object[] { "Hammer", "5", "1000", "Werkzeug",
            new Boolean(false), "Ein schöner Hammer" });
    model.addRow(new Object[] { "Computer", "2", "100000", "Elektronik",
            new Boolean(true), "Ein schöner Computer" });
    model.addRow(new Object[] { "Smartphone", "12", "10000", "Elektronik",
            new Boolean(false), "Ein schönes Smartphone" });
    model.addRow(new Object[] { "Hose", "6", "4000", "Kleidung",
            new Boolean(true), "Eine schöne Höse" });
    model.addRow(new Object[] { "Geschichtsbuch", "7", "1000", "Bücher",
            new Boolean(false), "Ein schönes Buch" });

}

}
```

and here is the part of the GUI, where I implement the model (It works if I use a `AbstractTableModel`):

```
            JTable table = new JTable(MyTableModel.model);
        JScrollPane scrollTable = new JScrollPane(table,
                ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_Table = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_Table.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 5, 5);
        gbc_Table.gridx = 0;
        gbc_Table.gridy = 1;
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        Dimension d = table.getPreferredSize();
        d.width = 500;
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(d);
        contentPanel.add(scrollTable, gbc_Table);
```

Comment: Do you have any exception?

Answer (score 0):

`MyTableModel.model` is empty. It's only populated when you call the constructor of MyTableModel, and you're never doing it. Using static non-final fields is bad practice. Making them public is even worse. And initializing static fields from a constructor is even worse.

Change your class to

```
public class MyTableModelFactory {

    public static DefaultTableModel create() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.addColumn("Col1");
        model.addColumn("Col2");
        model.addColumn("Col2");
        model.addColumn("Col2");
        model.addColumn("Col2");
        model.addColumn("Col2");

        model.addRow(new Object[] { "Hammer", "5", "1000", "Werkzeug",
                new Boolean(false), "Ein schöner Hammer" });
        model.addRow(new Object[] { "Computer", "2", "100000", "Elektronik",
                new Boolean(true), "Ein schöner Computer" });
        model.addRow(new Object[] { "Smartphone", "12", "10000", "Elektronik",
                new Boolean(false), "Ein schönes Smartphone" });
        model.addRow(new Object[] { "Hose", "6", "4000", "Kleidung",
                new Boolean(true), "Eine schöne Höse" });
        model.addRow(new Object[] { "Geschichtsbuch", "7", "1000", "Bücher",
                new Boolean(false), "Ein schönes Buch" });

    }
}
```

And use it as

```
JTable table = new JTable(MyTableModelFactory.create());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing is that the constructor of MyTableModel is never executed, so it won't populate the DefaultTableModel.

I can suggest you add a method to MyTableModel that adds the data you need.

```
public static void initialize(){
        model.addColumn("Col1");
        ...
        new Boolean(false), "Ein schönes Buch" });
}
```

And so, you can initialize the model before you create the JTable

```
TableModelControl.initialize();
JTable table = new JTable(TableModelControl.model);
```

Also, I am not a huge fan of public static models for Lists, Tables, and so on. I recomend not doing things like that in the future.